# CSS [attribute$="value"] selector not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 4 elements with a class of either `x-control-ui` or `y-control-ui`:

```
<div class="x-control-ui">x-control: <output id="x-control-output"></output></div> 
<input type="range" min="-4" max="4" step="0.1" value="0" class="param x-control-ui" id="x-control">

<div class="y-control-ui">y-control: <output id="y-control-output"></output></div> 
<input type="range" min="-4" max="4" step="0.1" value="0" class="param y-control-ui" id="y-control">
```

Using the `[attribute*="value"]`  selector works as expected, selecting them all:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[class*='-control-ui']")
NodeList(4) [div.x-control-ui.hidden, input#x-control.param.x-control-ui.hidden, div.y-control-ui.hidden, input#y-control.param.y-control-ui.hidden]
```

but if I change `*=` to `$=`, using the `[attribute$="value"]`  selector, then no elements are selected:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[class$='-control-ui']")
NodeList []
```

even though though both classnames end in `control-ui`.

The same behaviour is observed in up-to-date Chrome and Firefox.   I have checked the docs in MDN and consulted other sources, and all seem to indicate that the `$=` operator should select elements whose specified attribute (in this case, `class`) **ends with** the given text.

I have tried modifying the selector in various ways, to no avail.
What am I missing?

Comment: Using those selector operators with the `class` attribute is problematic, because the value of the attribute may change such that while the element still has the class name you're looking for, it may not be at the end of the overall attribute value. The order of class names in the attribute string is not important; they're separated by spaces, so dynamic updates can leave the elements the same as far as the set of classes, but different in terms of the raw value of the attribute. It's a fragile way of coding for the page.

Comment: @Pointy that explains it: if I do `[...document.querySelectorAll("[class*='-control-ui']")].forEach(el => el.classList.remove('hidden'));` then things work as expected.   You have made me realise that having separate classes like `control-ui` and `x-control-ui` is the way to go, and avoid partial attribute selectors.   If you turn your comment into an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I will make an answer, not because I need the reputation but because I think you are the first person in all the years of me telling this to people who has actually understood what I was talking about :)

Comment: Are you just curious to know or something else? as it looks you have enough classes there to do anything you want, why bother with that?

Comment: @Stickers the OP has seen the light. Examining the class attribute string as in the question is not reliable. There's the modern `.classList()` API, but it's just as easy to add another class (well, when possible).

Comment: You don't need separate classes to get the exact match, You can do `.document.querySelectorAll("[class*='-control-ui '],[class$='-control-ui']")]` because the end of the class must terminate with either a space or the end of the string. But the awkwardness of this has recently been raised within the W3C CSS working group. See [New selector to facilitate utility classes](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/10001)

Comment: But, `document.querySelectorAll('.x-control-ui, .y-control-ui')` will do it, no?

Comment: @Stickers yes but there are 26 letters in the alphabet :)  It's really a matter of style and preference. I tend to prefer approaches that are more solid, but that's my opinion (including the word "solid").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing about the `class` attribute in particular is that it's kind of an old hack. The classes for an element appear separated by spaces in the class attribute value; it's just a string. (Now, in 2024, there's the `classList` API, but 20 years ago that did not exist.)

The meaning of the class attribute is such that the ordering of the classes does not matter (well, it might in some bizarre edge cases, but that's another topic). So a class string of "something foo-control-ui" is functionally the same as "foo-control-ui something". Because code often modifies the class of an element by adding and removing class names, the value of that attribute string at any time could *mean* the same thing but *look* different.

Thus, your `*=` selector works because it looks for that fragment everywhere in the string. However, the `$=` selector only looks at the end of the class value. *Sometimes*, it might work, but it's a very fragile way to write code.

As you said in a comment, adding another class to be the "general" quality, and then a more specific class for the precise behavior (or whatever the class is supposed to do), is the more robust way to go. Within realistic bounds, it's basically no cost to add as many classes as you like: some for CSS rules, some for behaviors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing problem with the selector `[class$='-control-ui']`, it’s just because this selector seek for those elements whose class attribute ends with  `'-control-ui'` . but in your html elements the class names  ends with other characters like `div.x-control-ui.hidden`. So because of this `$= selector` not able to find these elements. modify your html.